# Div frame to fit 100% window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

My developer left me with a bunch of problems I'm trying to fix myself now. My responsive site has a frame that is designed to fit the window size, and when you change the window size the frame will resize accordingly.

One of the problems I am having lies at the bottom of the site, where normally on the desktop size the two sections of text hide and show one after the other as you scroll; then on a smaller tablet/mobile size this effect is switched off and instead stacks them on top of each other, which is fine, I understand that for mobile some trade offs occur.

The problem then is I can't get the frame to fill out the window size. I'm trying to locate how to fix this, but haven't had luck with basic number value changing etc. Any help is appreciated.

http://dev.matthewbugeja.com/

[image]

Comment: could not replicate the problem in chrome or firefox which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. I tested it in Firefox and it is doing it also.

Comment: what's your screen resolution?

Comment: I'm using a 2k 21:9 ratio screen, but the problem was still present on my 1080x1920, which should matter anyway as the problem occurs on window sizes much smaller than these.

Comment: ok since I can't see any code I'm not sure the cause of problem..But I'would recommend you to use this css: html,body{height: auto !important};

Answer (score 0):

try this CSS

```
div {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
div {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your question there is effect of jquery is append when we resize the window for small devices the div with classname is

> scrollmagic-pin-spacer

does not show check your jquery could hide this for small devices

Comment: Tried disabling scrollmagic, and also tried not letting itself disable on window shrinking, but still nothing is right. I think this is just beyond my ability to fix.